# Help me identify my Chilies

Tags: identification, chili

I need some help please, I grow my own chilies and I am struggling to identify them and not sure what they should look like for picking, what colour should they be?

[image]

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Also, you can include illustrations that appear within the text of your questions by clicking on the scenery/mountain silhouette button, and then adding images according to the instructions which appear, and you can adjust text of your questions and answers, by clicking on the 'edit' button in the lower left corner of your question screen & answer screen. Thank you, and Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you for your question; if could include an overall illustration of your Chili and close illustrations of the chili fruits, plant flowers, & leaves, an illustration of each if several different varieties, and overall plant height(s) and chili fruit size(s), could be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: If illustrations are unable to be posted, when ripe enough for harvesting, chili fruits  typically resemble the fruits from which the seeds of the plants they grow on come from ( unless the plants have hybridised), except that the new chili fruits generally are uncrinkled and possibly a bit plump, and might be greener, since some chili types tend to become reddish or orangish in colour as they ripen more. Thank you

Comment: Not to discourage anything here, but there are a lot of different varieties including many that look just like others.  You won't really know from looks for some of those until you actually eat them and even then you may not be certain.  :)  However, that all said, I love chilis and wish I could grow some here that are worth eating.  Right now the best results I have are from the very mild red peppers which are probably not really even considered chilis by those who are after the heat.

Comment: Hi All thank you for your feedback. I have included a few pictures, hope that is sufficient.

Comment: @DonovanScholtz I have proposed an edit to reorganize the images a bit, you can review it and accept if you like. And thanks for adding the images. :)

Comment: Thank you for including your great illustrations of your outstanding chilis! Your illustrations show excellent details, are highly visible & clear without additional magnifications, their size is igreat, they load rapidly, and the order they are in, one after another, is very clear & helpful for answering! Your illustrations are great as they are, so please keep your outstanding illustrations of your outstanding chilis just the way they are! Thank you!

Comment: Consider that they may be no-name chili. Cross-pollination is frequent, so the result is not more a cultivar (but if you can stabilize it, you may create your cultivar).

Comment: Where did you get them?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, I'd guess the first picture is Cayenne and that the last is a Jalapeño.